# Azure DevOps Copy Files Task is Prepending the Target Folder Name to Every File in a Nested Fashion

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have no idea why this is happening. The only way I know to describe this is that the Azure DevOps Copy Files task is prepending the Target Folder name to every file in a nested fashion over and over again, like Russian dolls.

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?

Here is my Copy Files task...pretty simple.

[Copy Files Task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjKJb.png)

2023-06-15T21:50:00.0844284Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\App_Code\app.config to Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:00.5103537Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:00.7947759Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:01.0291112Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:01.2603302Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:01.5265672Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:01.5680623Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config
...

2023-06-15T21:50:01.6058794Z Copying D:\GIS\agent02_work\605\s\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config to Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\Dist\App_Code\app.config

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure what caused this, but deleting the build pipeline and starting over with Clean set to true fixed the issue.

[Build Pipeline Clean Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbrDE.png)

Answer (score -1):

I assume, it's because of the target folder.

Refer [CopyFiles@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/copy-files-v2?view=azure-pipelines&tabs=yaml) documentation for target folder.

Change the target folder to `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)\out\outputs\Dist`.

Check this [Predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the target folder and the same thing happened with the extra folders in the path. Still not sure how this happened, but I deleted the build job and started over with Clean set to true, and then the working directory did not have all of those extra folders in the path.